# Apache forbidding any attempt at accessing an alias directory

Tags: windows-10, apache-http-server

Attempting to hook another drive into apache with alias. I'm using Windows 10 with apache 2.4.

```
DocumentRoot "G:\Other"
<Directory "G:\Other">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias "/s/" "E:\Other"
<Directory "E:\Other">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This gives 403 Forbidden on any page of the alias, the document root works fine but not the alias.

Access and error logs show nothing useful.

Comment: Does the Apache service _itself_ have permissions to access that drive? Is this a fixed/removable drive or some virtual mapping?

Comment: It's not a service, it's the complete program in a folder. Either way, it does. The drive is not encrypted or otherwise unaccessable, I started a different Apache server pointing to that drive and it works just fine. It's a fixed 2TB Western Digital.

Comment: Just tried moving the Apache root directory to my C drive instead of the drives I'm trying to serve. No luck. Also tried swapping the drives in terms of who is the alias, also did not work.

Comment: did you try using //computername/sharename/foldername or \\\\computername\\sharename\\foldername